# How can i send 10,000 NFT in a single transaction like we send EOS tokens

Tags: transactions, tokens, eosio.token, erc20

I have implemented the nft statndard in EOS but I am having issue that I can't send more than 60 tokens at a single time. In NFT standard each token has **unique id** so they need to be send one at a time. Is this thing doable in EOS, Or there are any other alternative approach available

If I m sending more that 50 tokens EOS local nodes through this error: `Error 3080006: Transaction took too long`  and this is quite obvious in this case. Do I need to shift to a standard like erc-20 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Do I need to shift to a standard like erc-20 ?
```

This really depends on what you're trying to achieve. The NFT and ERC-20 are fundamentally different. Do you understand the difference?

Non fungible tokens are used to manage ownership of unique items which are not equal in properties and value. An example for a non fungible item is when your friend lends you a rare baseball card with some unique signature of the baseball player on it which makes it special. Your friend will not be happy if you return a similar baseball card, even if it has the same picture on it if it misses the signature or is different in any way. He would expect the exact same card back.

Fungible is for regular tokens like BTC and FIAT currencies like US Dollars, where you can borrow 15 USD from a friend and later return 15 USD - not the exact same 15 USD but other bills and coins or a paypal transfer with the same value.

This is why there is a difference in processing time to transfer 10000 ERC-20 tokens vs transferring 10000 NFT tokens. In the first case, you do the math, deduct 10000 from the sending account balance and add 10000 to the receiving account.

In the NFT case, you are actually making 10000 different transfers of single tokens from one account to the other.

If you really need to transfer 10000 NFT tokens, you might need to increase the CPU resources for the account doing the transfer but you still might face the limits for processing time. You will need to break this down to smaller batches and manage the whole process using several transactions.